# How to make ContainerApp working even with probe errors?

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I have deployed Container App with Ingress, after couple of minutes when i want to check logs for this container with `az containerapp logs show -n<my-container-app> -g <my-resource-group>`  In return I get: `Could not find a replica for this app`. What does that mean? Why its not running? From logs I could see that my container was running successfully, however for some reason its not launched. I want it to be all the time active even if any checks that cause this issue returning errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Could not find a replica for this app

The above error indicates that the container instance executing your app is not at its current stage. The application within the container may have crashed or failed operation, or the container instance may have been terminated.

You can check the status of the container app by running the command

```
az containerapp show -n <my-container-app> -g <my-resource-group>
```

[image]

If the container is crashed create an Azure Container Instance to automatically restart your container instance if it fails or is terminated. To do this, you can use the `--restart-policy` flag when deploying your container and set it to `Always`.

**Command:**

```
az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myapp --image myimage:latest --command-line "echo hello" --restart-policy Never
```

Once, all the provision is successful you can use the same command to get the logs.

**Command:**

```
az containerapp logs show -n <your-app> -g <-resource-grp>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[az containerapp logs | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/logs?view=azure-cli-latest)